# How to get the latest cloudwatch log stream URL using Python Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm deploying some lambda functions and at the end, I need to print the complete URL of the latest CloudWatch log stream. So that other users can view the log directly by clicking the URL.

I've tried the below, but I need to print the complete URL.

```
     print("CloudWatch log stream name:", context.log_stream_name)
```

I believe this can be done by using [describe_log_streams](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.describe_log_streams) along with some tweaks. But I'm helpless where to start.

Comment: You know the log stream name, you know the log group and you know the region, there aren't any other dynamic parts in the url. You can just build the url by hand.

Comment: You mean this kind of URL? `https://<region>.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=<region>#logsV2:log-groups/log-group/<$-escaped-log-group>`

Comment: @Erwin Yes, exactly i need this kind of URL

Comment: Then you should have everything to get started. What is the problem?

Comment: @luk2302 I was trying to decode the URL. I found the solution and will post the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and its working as expected, please comment for any improvement.

```
def multiple_replace(text, adict):
    rx = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, adict)))
    def one_xlat(match):
        return adict[match.group(0)]
    return rx.sub(one_xlat, text)

def main(event, context):
    region = context.invoked_function_arn.split(':')[3]
    replace_map = {}
    replace_map['/']='$252F'
    replace_map['[']='$255B'
    replace_map['$']='$2524'
    replace_map[']']='$255D'

    cw_logs = 'https://' + region + '.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=' + region + '#logsV2:log-groups/log-group/' + context.log_group_name.replace('/', '%252F') + '/log-events/' + multiple_replace(context.log_stream_name,replace_map)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done much easier (just replace "$" before replacing other special characters, then "$" doesn't require any special treating is as "escape character"):

```
    region = context.invoked_function_arn.split(':')[3]
    log_stream_name = context.log_stream_name.replace('$','$2524').replace('/','$252F').replace('[','$255B').replace(']','$255D')
    log_group_name = context.log_group_name.replace('/', '$252F')
    cw_logs_url = 'https://' + region + '.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=' + region + '#logsV2:log-groups/log-group/'+ log_group_name  + '/log-events/' + log_stream_name
```